# Memcached partial object invalidated

Tags: object, memcached

We are caching a object of below class format.

public class CachedObject
{

```
@javax.persistence.Transient
public List<ObjectA> objectAs;

@javax.persistence.Transient
public Date cacheExpirationDate;
```

}

We have a process that checks the expiration date on the cached object and refreshes the cache before it expires. There is another process that also updates the cached object using replace (spymemcached) method if there are any updates. Updates normally happen to objectAs in our situation. The cached object is never evicted. We also started memcached with default slab (1MB) size settings.

The issue: When we fetch some objects we find that the cache object is not null, but the objectAs is null. We subsequently get null pointer exceptions when trying to do anything on objectAs. I checked and we always set objectAs value before caching/updating. I also saw the incomplete cached object from the telnet interface. When I refreshed the cache, it started showing the full object in the cache.

Can someone please suggest what could probably be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After running some more tests unit/integration, I found a case where this field was set to null. So my problem as stated in the question has nothing to do with memcached cache server. This is an application related issue.